# spool output of multiple oracle DB connections to a single file

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I would like to spool an output of an query from multiple databases (perform sqlplus connection to each database)into a single file and then send it as mail like (Backup report)

How can i achieve this?

Regards,
Arun

Comment: Give the databases permission to talk to each other.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't given a lot of detail about your environment or requirements, but perhaps a script like this:

```
sqlplus user/pw@db1 @query > logile
sqlplus user/pw@db2 @query >> logfile
sqlplus user/pw@db3 @query >> logfile
etc.
quit
```